# phpMyAdmin issue file not found

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Getting this error "**The requested URL /phpMyAdmin/db_structure.php was not found on this server.**" when clicks on the any of the database from the left bar.

I am using phpMyAdmin from MAMP pro. I tried reinstalling whole MAMP pro but still facing the same problem.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the file exist in the phpMyAdmin folder? Did you check the accessright in the Apache config ?

Comment: yes it exists in phpMyAdmin folder. How i can check the access right in the apache config?

Comment: Do you have this line in your config.inc.php: $cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri']? If so, what does it contain?

Comment: No. config.inc.php doesn't contain this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by reinstalling MAMP pro.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your Apache config (httpd.conf) looks like something like that :

```
        Alias /phpMyAdmin "[Your path to phpmyadmin]"
        <Directory "[Your path to phpmyadmin]">
                AllowOverride All
                Options FollowSymlinks
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
```

Note that you may want to be more restrictive about the allow/deny config.

Comment: these two were different from your's . Options Indexes MultiViews
AllowOverride None. Even i tried changing same as your. But still not working.

Comment: Yes, I checked it twice.